# why on nuget.org the supported frameworks for a package are not listed?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

Why is nuget.org not listing supported frameworks for a package?
 Isn't this information important?

To be more specific, I am talking about the package page

https://nuget.org/packages/[PackageName]/

If this would get displayed on the page, I assume the NuGet manager in Visual Studio will be able to display it too. I will be able to know exactly what platforms the package targets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your original question was

> Why is nuget.org not listing supported frameworks for a package?

It's apparently [considered P3](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/622) but it is planned for the [major gallery redesign](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/1266).

Comment: more than 2 years later NOTHING has happened -- neither in www gallery nor in VS2015's brand new NuGet 3.0 experience

Comment: Some open issues about this feature: #2787, #2805, #4077, #4598, #4843
I am baffled as to why this isn't a priority...

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you why NuGet Gallery doesn't implement this feature. Since it's open source and hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery), you are free to implement it yourself and send a pull request to the authors.

For now you can use [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/) to do it manually. Just choose **Open a package from online feed** option from the main menu and find your package. NPE will download and display its contents for you. You can see which frameworks are supported there.

[image]

Comment: thank you, I already know about the Package Explorer but it's useful to mention it